# WooCommerce Amazon Fulfillment SellerSKU is invalid

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce Amazon Fulfillment plugin

but when I try to Send to Amazon FBA

I get this error --> the SellerSKU for Item Id: item-1-PTCT-CC-1SM is invalid.

I don't know how to figure it out.

Can any one help me please??

Thanks

Adil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure about how the plugin works but as per the error message the SellerSku (woocommerce SKU) isn't matches with FBA product having Item Id - item-1-PTCT-CC-1SM.
You can once cross-check the SKU on both platform i.e Amazon & Woocommerce
Thanks